# offset() returns different values in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I am trying to position a popup dynamically relative to its target. It works well in desktop browsers. But in mobile browsers, the positions are buggy. It is mainly because, in desktop browsers, offset() of an element gives the same value even when the page is scrolled. But in mobile browsers, offset() provides different values when the page is scrolled. To get actual offset, we need to do,

```
offset.left -= window.pageXOffset
offset.top -= window.pageYOffset
```

But this does not happen in all the cases. This happens only when the page is not scaled in mobile browsers.
This issue is reported here(https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3187). 
Whereas in this issue page, they have mentioned that this issue occurs only when the mobile browser is scaled.

How to find the correct offset irrespective of desktop / mobile / ipad browsers?

I have derived a solution to get the actual offset of the element:

```
function getOffset( element ){
  var $body = $('body');
  var offset = element.offset();
    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
      var temp = $('<span>').css({
        position:'absolute',
        height:'20px',
        width:'20px',
        top:'0px',
        left:'0px'
      }).appendTo( $body );
      correctionOffset = temp.offset();
      correctionOffset.left = correctionOffset.left - parseFloat( $body.css('margin-left') ) - parseFloat( $body.css('border-left-width') ) ; 
      correctionOffset.top = correctionOffset.top - parseFloat( $body.css('margin-top') ) - parseFloat($body.css('border-top-width') ) ; 
      temp.remove();
      offset.left -= ( correctionOffset.left );
      offset.top -= ( correctionOffset.top );
  }
  return offset;
}
```

Is this the right way to achieve the correct offset of the element in mobile browsers even when it is scaled?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this it's work :

```
<li><a href="#scroll_to_gallery" class="bnrbuttons"></a></li>


 <script>
 jQuery(document).on('click', '.bnrbuttons a', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    if ( $(window).width() < 767) { //Set here window width accourding to your need

        jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery( jQuery.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top + 230
        }, 500);
        
    }
  else{
      jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery( jQuery.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top - 65
        }, 500);
  }
        
});
```